# What's the actual use case for using Timelock (queue) for governance?

Tags: openzeppelin, governance, timelock

> If there was no timelock to begin with, this step (execute) can be ran immediately after the proposal succeeds.

To me above makes more sense than adding a timelock to send another `queue` transaction and wait for some time to run `execute` afterwards. It sounds like proposer role always need to wait for proposal to succeed and run `queue` subsequently, which involves extra step.

What's the actual use case for `queue`? why is this recomended? In their [doc](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/docs/modules/ROOT/pages/governance.adoc)

> It is good practice to add a timelock to governance decisions. This allows users to exit the system if they disagree with a decision before it is executed

I don't quite get this, but I assume user who has already casted vote can revoke during this period? If yes, does it mean they are going against the proposal or abstain from it? how does this process work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timelock extensions add a delay for governance decisions to be executed. The workflow is extended to require a queue step before execution.

We want to have a queue (delay) so that if there are any significant changes in the protocol, the users/applications that use the protocol can prepare accordingly for the effects of implementation for them. since it is successful and is very likely to get executed after the delay period is over.

Also, till the proposal is executed the proposer needs to maintain the proposal threshold (including while queued in timelock). Otherwise, the cancel function can be called by the proposal creator, or any Ethereum address if the proposal creator fails to maintain more delegated votes than the proposal threshold.